# Passing date as search parameter issue

Tags: php, cakephp, date

When a user searches post by date, I need to pass the date as a search parameter through the url.

Like : http://siteurl/post/index/created:03/15/2012

As you can see the date format is `mm/dd/yy` which is creating an issue, as a result I'm getting only `03` as a value in the request.

**Edited** : Some code from my params i get in controller.

```
Array
(

[controller] => posts

[action] => index

[named] => Array
    (
        [created] => 03
    )

[pass] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15
        [1] => 2012
    )

[plugin] => 
[form] => Array
    (
    )

[url] => Array
    (
        [url] => /posts/index/created:03/15/2012
    )

[isAjax] => 
)
```

Is there a way that a user can select date in `mm/dd/yy` format and then I can change to another format after submitting the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the date into time stamp and pass using:

```
$date = '03/15/2012';

$timestamp = strtotime($date);
```

pass this to the url.

Convert back to 'mm/dd/yy' using:

```
echo date('m/d/Y',$timestamp);
```

Comment: Get the post in your cakephp controller and use redirect method there.

Comment: Alternatively you can use the database format: `YYYY-MM-DD` as passed argument. as long as the date only contains `-` you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters that are not named are passed to the action, so you could also do this in your controller:

```
function index($month, $day, $year)
{

}
```

and if you still want to use this action without passing any date, use this and test if values are given:

```
function index($month = null, $day = null, $year = null)
{

}
```

**Edit**

If it comes from a form, you should maybe use a POST instead of a GET for your form and retrieve the value like this:

```
function index()
{
    if(isset($this->data['Post']['created']))
    {
        $created = $this->data['Post']['created'];

        //Do you search here
    }
}
```

There are may solutions depending on your needs... ;-)

Comment: I have edited my question. you can have look on the parameters array i am getting.

Comment: In these parameters, the URL shows a colon between `created` and `03` and the action is `index`. Are you sure of the URL you are using ? It should be without colon (like in your question), and the action should be called `created` in your controller

Comment: hmm... ok. Due to the form of the URL in your question, I thought you wanted to use an action called `created`. If you do want to use `index`, just remove the `created:` part. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I will get $day & $year by your anser..but what about $month (i.e. `03`) as you can see in params it is not setting as `pass` but it is getting in created...

Comment: as you said `just remove the created: `  - but it is a search form field name

Comment: With this solution, the URL should only be `/posts/index/03/15/2012`. But if you do want a named param, Ben or Robert solutions are probably correct.

Comment: Ok thanks...I will try as named is necessary as user can search by more than fields..

Comment: I made a last edit. As I said, there are many solutions, depending of your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the date value when passing it as part of the URL. The controller action that handles the request will need to use [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to convert it back to the original date value with the slashes.